# How to display count for different values sharing the same prefix?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am trying to count number of times particular sequence occurs. Say a column - 'testC' in a table - 'testT' as characters such as 'DS-PP', 'WQ-PP', 'FF-PP', 'DS-PP', 'DS-PP', 'FF-PP'
I want the result to be like

```
DS-PP - 3
FF-PP - 2
WQ-PP - 1
```

how can I achieve that. So far I have got

```
SELECT count(testC) from testT where testC like '%-PP%' group by testC
```

This gives me the count But doesnt say for which. I need to add something in select to get the DS-PP and so on

Note: testC column can have anything (it is a text field) say - 'DP-PP was here.' I want it to show just DP-PP not the whole sentence is that possible.

Check this
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0c29/1

Comment: How does that sql work there is no column mentioned in the like condition in the where clause?

Comment: Please work on asking the real question and using appropriate tags. I've made some edits, but they *won't show the whole story* cleanly. Include the *actual data* and *current query output* - this should should include example data like `DP-PP was here`, which is lost in the very small note at the bottom.

Comment: Anyway, my recommendation (if fixing the schema to remove the de-normalization is not an option) would be to use a nested query and use [`SUBSTR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) on testC before it's selected for the `COUNT`. This may have a negative impact on index usage.

Comment: If using SUBSTR/INSTR (INSTR could find the index of `-PP`) doest meet the required rules, then you're pretty much up a creek with the schema - and might be anyway if it covers many rows due to the horrid plan it will result in. In this case I'd really urge fixing the model for accommodate the requirements.

Comment: thanks I knew i had to restructure it but was hoping for a quick solution for now until i redo it.

Comment: Also, make sure to make the post the query/data *stand alone*. An SQL Fiddle is nice, but it should be *replicated* in the post itself :D

Comment: is there a way to to case  case when testC='%%-PP' then '%%-PP' something to wildcard the 2 character infront of -PP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `TestC` in the `select`:

```
SELECT TestC, count(testC)
from testT
where testC like '%-PP%'
group by testC
```

EDIT:

Definitely a much more reasonable question.

```
select substr(TestC, locate('-pp', TestC) - 2, 5), count(*)
from testT
where locate('-pp', TestC) > 2
group by substr(TestC, locate('-pp', TestC) - 2, 5)
```

This assumes that you want the two characters before the `'-pp'`.  It filters out any rows where `'-pp'` starts on the first or second character.

Answer (score 2):

didnt you miss `WHERE testC` clause ? AND you missed to select `testC` also.

```
    SELECT testC, count(testC) from testT WHERE testC like '%-PP%' group by testC
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47a59/2)

for your second suggestion .you can locate -PP first and then substract characters like that :

```
 select substr(TestC, locate('-pp', TestC) - 2, 5) as testc, count(*)
 from testT
 where locate('-pp', TestC) > 2
 group by substr(TestC, locate('-pp', TestC) - 2, 5)
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0c29/17)

Comment: sorry i missed where while asking this question

Comment: you missed also column after where